# Contact Number repeating in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am facing a issue while retrieving contact list from the phone i am getting same contact number for all contact names in Xamarin.Forms. I am new in Xamarin and want to load all phone contacts in listview.
Here is my Code:

```
  private List<ContactMenu> LoadAllContacts()
    {
        List<ContactMenu> getContactNamesAndNumber = new List<ContactMenu>();
        //Bind Contacts
        var forContactNames = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;
        string[] forContactNumbers = {
        ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName
    };
        var forContactNumber = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri;
        string[] forContactDisplayNumber = { ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number };
        var names = ManagedQuery(forContactNames, forContactNumbers, null, null, null);
        var nameList = new List<string>();
        var number = ManagedQuery(forContactNumber, forContactDisplayNumber, null, null, null);
        var numbeList = new List<string>();
        if (names.MoveToFirst() && number.MoveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                getContactNamesAndNumber.Add(new ContactMenu
                {
                   ContactName =  names.GetString(names.GetColumnIndex(forContactNumbers[1])), ContactNumber = number.GetString(number.GetColumnIndex(forContactDisplayNumber[1]))
                });
                numbeList.Add(number.GetString(number.GetColumnIndex(forContactDisplayNumber[1])));
                nameList.Add(names.GetString(names.GetColumnIndex(forContactNumbers[1])));
            } while (names.MoveToNext());
        }
        ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.ContactItemView, numbeList);
        return getContactNamesAndNumber;
    }
```

And My Xaml :

```
 <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <Label Text="Please Select Contact" TextColor="Black" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="Medium" Font="16"></Label>
    <ListView x:Name="myContacts" HorizontalOptions="Start" ItemTapped="myContacts_ItemTapped">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding ContactName}" DetailColor="Green" TextColor="Black"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `ManagedQuery`s, `names` and `number` but are only advancing the `names` query via `names.MoveToNext()` at the end of your `do` loop.

You should remove one of the `ManagedQuery` and return all the columns that you need in just one query so you can obtain the name and matching number from the `same` data row.

Comment: I tried but only names are coming not numbers can you please edit the please correct .